# Which semirings have enough injectives in their category of modules?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, universal-algebra

Let $R$ be a semiring and $Mod_R$ its category of modules. That is, $R$ is a monoid in the monoidal category of commutative monoids and $Mod_R$ is its category of modules in the usual sense.

**Question 1:** For which semirings $R$ does $Mod_R$ have enough injectives?

**Question 2:** Which subvarieties of those of the form $Mod_R$ (with $R$ a semiring) have enough injectives?

Of course, if $R$ is a ring, then $Mod_R$ has enough injectives. But the category of commutative monoids $Mod_\mathbb{N}$ does not have enough injectives; the injective objects are still the divisible abelian groups, and a commutative monoid embeds into one of these iff it is cancellative.

The property of having enough injectives is not actually useful if these injectives can't be used to form resolutions, so I'd be most interested in an answer about having enough regular-injectives (an object is regular-injective if it lifts against regular monomorphisms, and there are enough of them if every object embeds into a regular-injective via a regular monomorphism). But it appears that the question of having enough injectives in the usual sense has been more widely studied in the literature. In particular, results of [Kearnes](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-105-04/S0002-9939-1989-0952317-5/) come very close to answering this question, since he addresses both congruence-modular varieties (which include subvarieties of $Mod_R$ where $R$ is a ring) and varieties of semigroups (roughly $Mod_\mathbb{N}$). So I'd be interested in an answer addressing having enough injectives in the usual sense, too.

There's apparently a [general answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042299/when-do-universal-algebraic-varieties-have-enough-injectives) for all varieties, but I'm hoping one can be a bit more explicit in the specific cases I'm asking about.

Actually, Kearnes shows that a congruence-modular variety (every congruence lattice is modular) has enough injectives iff it has amalgamation and is residually small (i.e. has a cogenerating set). Module categories over a ring are congruence-modular, but the category of semigroups, and thus probably many other module categories over a semiring, are not. So I'd also like to ask:

**Question 3:** Which varieties of the form $Mod_R$ with $R$ a semiring are congruence-modular?

**Question 4:** Which varieties of the form $Mod_R$ are residually small?

But if Question 1 alone is answered, I'll accept and repackage the rest of these into another question.

**EDIT:** A word more about the "general answer" I linked to above, leading to a partial answer to Question 1. The general answer says in particular that if a variety has enough injectives, it must have the "congruence extension property": any congruence can be extended along any monomorphism. For any module $M$ over a semiring $R$, we can formally adjoin additive inverses via the usual fraction construction to get a "groupification" $M \to M[-\mathbb{N}]$. The kernel of this map consists exactly of the (additively) noncancellative elements of $M$, so if $M$ contains a cancellative element, the image $M'$ of $M$ under this map is nonzero. Then there is a quotient $M''$ of $M'$ where we identify $2m$ with $m$ for every $m \in M'$. The kernel of this quotient consists of the elements of $M'$ with additive inverses. As long as there is an element of $M'$ without an additive inverse, the congruence generated by this equivalence relation does not extend to $M[-\mathbb{N}]$. So if there is a module $M$ containing a cancellative element without an additive inverse, then the congruence extension property fails. Moreover, this happens if and only if the unit map $\mathbb{N} \to R$ is injective and does not extend to $\mathbb{Z} \to R$, since in this case we can take $M = R$. So if $R$ does not satisfy a "uniform idempotency" law $nr = (n+1)r$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $Mod_R$ has enough injectives if and only if $R$ is a ring. But I'm not sure what to do in the idempotent case.

Although, the "congruence extension property" seems to have a lot to do with the fact that classically one looks at injectives rather than regular-injectives, so this is a bit unsatisfying.

Comment: Oh -- the answer to question 3 as stated is that $Mod_R$ is congruence-modular if and only if $R$ is a ring. This follows from the fact that a variety is modular iff it has Mal'cev terms, and you can work through what they must be explicitly in this case to see that $1 \in R$ has an additive inverse. But I'd still be interested in the answer to Question 3 for subvarieties of $Mod_R$'s.

Comment: Actually, a variety has a Mal'cev term iff it is congruence-permutable, which in turns implies modularity (but the former is much stronger). There are terms for modularity, by Day, and a very neat set by Gumm.

Comment: Oh thanks! As you can see, universal algebra is not my strong suit. But I just checked Gumm's paper (Theorem 1.4 of "Congruence modularity is permutability composed with distributivity"), and the terms he has are what I was using. Perhaps I should say "generalized Mal'cev terms" or something?

Comment: Perhaps "Gumm terms (for modularity)" would be just fine!